# How to make a jquery pop up, pop up with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://madaxedesign.co.uk/

On my home page I have created a anchor at the bottom of the page under the name of "get in touch" that has a class of Contact-pop-up and in the Jquery have added a.contact-pop-up to the Jquery so onClick it will perform the script but when I go to test by pressing on the get in touch anchor it doesn't seem to work.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this would be?

Jquery

```
    $('a.contact , a.contact_footer , a.contact-pop-up').click(function() {
    $("#popup").load("contact.php");
    // Getting the variable's value from a link
    var 
    show = $('#popup').css('display', 'block'),
    popup = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(popup).fadeIn(300);

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(popup).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(popup).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(popup).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.cross, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , #popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
   <p>Please take the time to look through my portfolio and if anything interests you or   have any questions, please
```

Get In Touch.

Thank you

Comment: Could you post the relevant code here rather than linking?

Comment: Questions with only links to someones site are not very useful to future users with similar issues once the sites is fixed, changed or gone. Please always post the relevant code, HTML and CSS and if possible in addition a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Sorrry I was meant to..

Comment: Yeah I normally do. My bad. Is there anything else I could do to make this easy for you guys to understand. Thanks

Comment: You have two versions of jquery included. Maybe it's the case? And you have error in your `bundle.php` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want something like this...

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" id="someId">
    <p class="arch-pop-msg">Please take the time to look through my portfolio and if anything interests you or   have any questions, please</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".popup").dialog({ modal: true, 
                     position : 'center', 
                     width: 380, 
                     height: 90, 
                     autoOpen: false, 
                     closeOnEscape: true, 
                     resizable: false,  
                     showTitlebar: false  
                   });
```

CSS: add css as per your need